# fetch videos with duration less than 10 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, video, core-data, phasset

I am integrating custom image picker and i have to show videos from camera roll whose duration is less than 10 seconds. Below code fetches all videos from gallery but i want to apply predicate to filter based on duration as well.

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true) ]
    options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
    assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)
    print(assets ?? "no video found")
    collectionView.reloadData()
```

Please let me know if anyone has any idea regarding the same.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the condition to the predicate

```
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d AND duration < 10", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
```

Comment: How to do this with PHPicker?

Comment: @Trevor I'm not familiar with PHPicker.